# Querying values within range A[i],A[j] in index range i,j in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, count

Suppose we have an array of n elements(unsorted). Given a query with two parameters i and j where i and j are indexes to the array, I want to return the number of values x st. x is within range `A[i],A[j]`(exclusive) and x is itself in index range `i<indexof(x)<j`.

As an example the array is `[3,6,7,1,2,4,9,1]`

```
i=1 j=7
A[i]=3 A[j]=9
```

so values within range 3,9 from index 1 to 7 are

```
6,7,4
```

which results in 3 values.

I definitely need to do some preprocessing so that I can answer the query in O(logn)time.
I tried to solve this using a Fenwick tree, but I guess it needs some modification and plus I do not need to do any updates on the array, but just answer queries.

Edit: Precomputing of O(n^2) and O(1) query is not a valid option for me

Comment: what's your expected runtime for pre-processing? and what's the range for `a[i]`?

Comment: the result of i=2,j=4 (a[i]=6,a[j]=1) is 0?

Comment: @amit yeah result is 0. as 7 is not in range (6,1).

Comment: @nevets any element of array is in integer range.

Comment: so I expect a pre-processing of O(nlogn)

Comment: Do you need an online or an offline solution(is it possible to read all queries before processing any of them)?

Comment: an offline solution is possible, check my answer.

Comment: And if a number x appears twice in the range, should it be counted twice? For example, if an array is (0, 1, 1, 2) and the query is i = 0, j = 3, is the answer 1 or 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can solve this by using a merge sort related segment tree. At each node corresponding to the range [l, r], the array stored in this node will be the sorted array of A[l...r]. We can preprocess this in O(n log n) time and the space complexity will also be O(n log n) since each element appears only one time at each height of the tree, which is equal to O(log n).

The naive approach to build this tree is to sort the array at each node with an O(n log n) algorithm which gives you a total time complexity of O(n log^2 n). But I've already mentioned that this procedure looks like merge sort, so we can use the same procedure to obtain a time complexity of O(n log n) building time.

For example let's consider the first four elements of your example array [3, 6, 7, 1]. The tree I described will look like this:

```
    [1,3,6,7]
       /    \ 
  [3,6]     [1,7]
   / \       / \
 [3]  [6]  [7] [1]
```

Now queries can be done in O(log^2 n) time if you binary search the elements at the corresponding node.

Building time: O(n log n)

Query time: O(log^2 n)

Edit (code for building the tree in C++, querying is left as an exercise):

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_N = 10000;

int A[MAX_N], N; // the array of the integers
vector<int> T[MAX_N * 4];

void merge(vector<int>& C, vector<int>& A, vector<int>& B){
  int i = 0, j = 0, n = A.size(), m = B.size();
  C.assign(n + m, 0);
  while(i < n || j < m){
    if(i == n) C[i + j] = B[j], j++;
    else if(j == m) C[i + j] = A[i], i++;
    else {
      if(A[i] <= B[j]) {
        C[i + j] = A[i];
        i++;
      } else {
        C[i + j] = B[j];
        j ++;
      }
    }
  }
}

void build(int n, int L, int R){
  if(L == R) T[n] = vector<int>(1, A[L]);
  else {
    build(n * 2, L, (L + R) / 2);
    build(n * 2 + 1, (L + R) / 2 + 1, R);
    merge(T[n], T[n * 2], T[n * 2 + 1]);
  }
}

int main(){
  N = 4;
  A[0] = 3, A[1] = 6, A[2] = 7, A[3] = 1;
  build(1, 0, N - 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. And you could improve query time to O(log N) with fractional cascading.

Comment: thanks. One thing I did not get in querying is that,(going from the example), the nodes will correspond to sorted arrays with certain indexes. In the example, 1-4, 1-2 3-4 , 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4. So I do not understand what to do if i.e the query is 2-4 as there is no direct  corresponding node.

Comment: We will do the queries at node 2-2 and 3-4 and add the results up. There are at most log(n) such nodes we have to do binary search, thus an O(log^2(n)) time complexity. Apparently one can speed this up with fractional cascading, but I haven't checked this out.

Comment: ok thanks I will try O(log^2(n)) first and see. Perhaps that will be enough

Comment: @user78451 The constants on fractional cascading aren't wonderful; I wouldn't expect much of a speedup if any.

Comment: This data structure is usually called a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree).

Comment: Ok I implemented the naive approach, but that binary search is really messy the one where you need to count the elements that lie in the range in the node. Plus, it turns out that it is not exclusive. I need to count equal elements once and the ones in the range exclusively, twice. I am not sure even 2 binary searches is enough. i will consult fractional cascading now.

Comment: Search for the first element greater than A[i] and the last element less than A[j] and the elements between them will be the count.

Comment: I realized that we can improve this to O(n log n) by using persistent segment tree. See this link http://blog.anudeep2011.com/persistent-segment-trees-explained-with-spoj-problems/ for more about persistent segment trees.

Answer (score 0):

It's can be solved by Fenwick's tree. First let's do it under an assumption that all integers are smaller than 10^6.

The problem that prevents you from using Fenwick's directly is: if your queries come after you finished Fenwick's Tree setup, querying (`a[i]`, `a[j]`) will involve some numbers `a[k]` that `k > j` to be counted. A solution to this is to **sort the queries based on its right side**, and complete all queries with right index `j` right after you complete a Fenwick update of `a[j]`. This will ensure that the numbers come from later index won't affect previous count.

If all numbers are within integer range, map them downto `[1..N]`, where `N` is the size of your array before you start the routine mentioned above.

The overall complexity will be `O(Q log Q + Q log N)`, where `Q` is the number of queries, and `N` is the size of your array.

Comment: yeah this sounds reasonable and not that hard to implement. But what about the values a[k] that are in the range (a[i],a[j]) and k<i? Because as far as I know Fenwick is for the whole array and we still have the left part k<i to be taken care of right?

Comment: you need to subtract them, i.e. `Fenwick_Sum(a[j]) - Fenwick_Sum(a[i] - 1)`.